# Allocate 3D matrix in one big chunk

Tags: c, malloc

I'd like to allocate a 3D matrix in one big chunk. It should be possible to access this matrix in the `[i][j][k]` fashion, without having to calculate the linearized index every time.

I think it should be something like below, but I'm having trouble filling the `...`

```
double ****matrix = (double ****) malloc(...)
for (int i = 0; i < imax; i++) {
    matrix[i] = &matrix[...]
    for (int j = 0; j < jmax; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = &matrix[...]
            for (int k = 0; k < kmax; k++) {
                matrix[i][j][k] = &matrix[...]
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with one simple `malloc()` call in C (not in C++, though, there are no variable length arrays in C++):

```
void foo(int imax, int jmax, int kmax) {
    double (*matrix)[jmax][kmax] = malloc(imax*sizeof(*matrix));
    //Allocation done. Now fill the matrix:
    for(int i = 0; i < imax; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < jmax; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < kmax; k++) {
                matrix[i][j][k] = ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that C allows `jmax` and `kmax` to be dynamic values that are only known at runtime. That is the ability that's missing in C++, which makes C arrays much more powerful than their C++ counterpart.

---

The only drawback of this approach, as WhozCraig rightly notes, is that you can't return the resulting matrix as the return value of the function without resorting to a `void*`. However, you can return it by reference like this:

```
void foo(int imax, int jmax, int kmax, double (**outMatrix)[jmax][kmax]) {
    *outMatrix = malloc(imax*sizeof(**outMatrix));
    double (*matrix)[jmax][kmax] = *outMatrix;    //avoid having to write (*outMatrix)[i][j][k] everywhere

    ...  //as above
}
```

This function would need to be called like this:

```
int imax = ..., jmax = ..., kmax = ...;
double (*myMatrix)[jmax][kmax];
foo(imax, jmax, kmax, &myMatrix);
```

That way you get full type checking on the inner two dimension sizes even though they are runtime values.

Comment: This is the simplest way by far. Now just craft a way to *return* `matrix` and you're home-free. If the caller prepares a `double (*)[jmax][kmax] p = get_matrix(imax, jmax, kmax);` then `get_matrix` can simply return `void*` and C will cope with doing the right thing.

Comment: @WhozCraig True. I added a part about returning this stuff from a function now.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that the matrix passed in to `foo` needs to be declared like `double (*matrix)[0][0]` to avoid warnings. If you don't care about warnings, `double ***matrix` will work.

Comment: @AustinMullins No. The declared array sizes must fit with the actual `jmax` and `kmax` parameters. Passing a `double***` would be plain wrong since there is no pointer array involved in my solution, and passing a pointer to an array of the wrong size won't work because the compiler will calculate the wrong offsets. You have undefined behavior in both cases. I added a short snippet with correct invocation of `foo()` now.

Comment: Weird. It worked on my compiler. I didn't think the compiler did array size type checking on function calls. Good to know.

Comment: @AustinMullins The hard to grasp thing is, that the declaration `void foo(int a[3])` decays to `void foo(int* a)` while `void foo(int (*a)[3])` means exactly what it says. It's only the outer dimension of an array that decays into a pointer, a pointer does not decay. So, the declaration `void foo(int a[5][3])` is really the same as `void foo(int (*a)[3])` which cannot decay further. (I do hope that this clarifies more than it confuses...)

Comment: I got that `foo(int (*a)[3])` is different from `foo(int **a)`, but the compiler (gcc 4.8.1 on MinGW) didn't even raise a warning when I passed in a `int (*a)[0]` variable. I didn't think it actually checked the array size.

Comment: @AustinMullins Curious. When I compile this little code snippet `void foo(int (*a)[3]); int main() { int (*a)[0]; foo(a); }` with `gcc` version 4.7.2, I do get the expected warning "passing argument [...] from incompatible pointer type".

Answer (score 2):

For the single allocation to be possible and work, you need to lay out the resulting memory like this:

- `imax` units of `double **`
- `imax * jmax` units of `double *`
- `imax * jmax * kmax` units of `double`

Further, the '`imax` units of `double **`' must be allocated first; you can reorder the other two sections, but it is most sensible to deal with them in the order listed.

You also need to be able to assume that `double` and `double *` (and `double **`, but that's not much of a stretch) are sufficiently well aligned that you can simply allocate the chunks contiguously.  That is going to hold OK on most 64-bit systems with type `double`, but be aware of the possibility that it does not hold on 32-bit systems or for other types than `double` (basically, the assumption could be problematic when `sizeof(double) != sizeof(double *)`).

With those caveats made, then this code works cleanly (tested on Mac OS X 10.10.2 with GCC 4.9.1 and Valgrind version `valgrind-3.11.0.SVN`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef double Element;

static Element ***alloc_3d_matrix(size_t imax, size_t jmax, size_t kmax)
{
    size_t i_size = imax * sizeof(Element **);
    size_t j_size = imax * jmax * sizeof(Element *);
    size_t k_size = imax * jmax * kmax * sizeof(Element);

    Element ***matrix = malloc(i_size + j_size + k_size);

    if (matrix == 0)
        return 0;

    printf("i = %zu, j = %zu, k = %zu; sizes: i = %zu, j = %zu, k = %zu; "
           "%zu bytes total\n",
           imax, jmax, kmax, i_size, j_size, k_size, i_size + j_size + k_size);
    printf("matrix          = %p .. %p\n", (void *)matrix,
           (void *)((char *)matrix + i_size + j_size + k_size));

    Element **j_base = (void *)((char *)matrix + imax * sizeof(Element **));
    printf("j_base = %p\n", (void *)j_base);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < imax; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = &j_base[i * jmax];
        printf("matrix[%zu]       = %p (%p)\n",
               i, (void *)matrix[i], (void *)&matrix[i]);
    }

    Element *k_base = (void *)((char *)j_base + imax * jmax * sizeof(Element *));
    printf("k_base = %p\n", (void *)k_base);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < imax; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = &k_base[(i * jmax + j) * kmax];
            printf("matrix[%zu][%zu]    = %p (%p)\n",
                   i, j, (void *)matrix[i][j], (void *)&matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    /* Diagnostic only */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < imax; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < kmax; k++)
                printf("matrix[%zu][%zu][%zu] = %p\n",
                       i, j, k, (void *)&matrix[i][j][k]);
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t i_max = 3;
    size_t j_max = 4;
    size_t k_max = 5;

    Element ***matrix = alloc_3d_matrix(i_max, j_max, k_max);
    if (matrix == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate matrix[%zu][%zu][%zu]\n", i_max, j_max, k_max);
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < i_max; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < j_max; j++)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < k_max; k++)
                matrix[i][j][k] = (i + 1) * 100 + (j + 1) * 10 + k + 1;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < i_max; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < j_max; j++)
        {
            for (size_t k = k_max; k > 0; k--)
                printf("[%zu][%zu][%zu] = %6.0f\n", i, j, k-1, matrix[i][j][k-1]);
        }
    }

    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output (with some boring bits omitted):

```
i = 3, j = 4, k = 5; sizes: i = 24, j = 96, k = 480; 600 bytes total
matrix          = 0x100821630 .. 0x100821888
j_base = 0x100821648
matrix[0]       = 0x100821648 (0x100821630)
matrix[1]       = 0x100821668 (0x100821638)
matrix[2]       = 0x100821688 (0x100821640)
k_base = 0x1008216a8
matrix[0][0]    = 0x1008216a8 (0x100821648)
matrix[0][1]    = 0x1008216d0 (0x100821650)
matrix[0][2]    = 0x1008216f8 (0x100821658)
matrix[0][3]    = 0x100821720 (0x100821660)
matrix[1][0]    = 0x100821748 (0x100821668)
matrix[1][1]    = 0x100821770 (0x100821670)
matrix[1][2]    = 0x100821798 (0x100821678)
matrix[1][3]    = 0x1008217c0 (0x100821680)
matrix[2][0]    = 0x1008217e8 (0x100821688)
matrix[2][1]    = 0x100821810 (0x100821690)
matrix[2][2]    = 0x100821838 (0x100821698)
matrix[2][3]    = 0x100821860 (0x1008216a0)
matrix[0][0][0] = 0x1008216a8
matrix[0][0][1] = 0x1008216b0
matrix[0][0][2] = 0x1008216b8
matrix[0][0][3] = 0x1008216c0
matrix[0][0][4] = 0x1008216c8
matrix[0][1][0] = 0x1008216d0
matrix[0][1][1] = 0x1008216d8
matrix[0][1][2] = 0x1008216e0
matrix[0][1][3] = 0x1008216e8
matrix[0][1][4] = 0x1008216f0
matrix[0][2][0] = 0x1008216f8
…
matrix[2][2][4] = 0x100821858
matrix[2][3][0] = 0x100821860
matrix[2][3][1] = 0x100821868
matrix[2][3][2] = 0x100821870
matrix[2][3][3] = 0x100821878
matrix[2][3][4] = 0x100821880
[0][0][4] =    115
[0][0][3] =    114
[0][0][2] =    113
[0][0][1] =    112
[0][0][0] =    111
[0][1][4] =    125
[0][1][3] =    124
[0][1][2] =    123
[0][1][1] =    122
[0][1][0] =    121
[0][2][4] =    135
…
[2][2][0] =    331
[2][3][4] =    345
[2][3][3] =    344
[2][3][2] =    343
[2][3][1] =    342
[2][3][0] =    341
```

There is a lot of diagnostic output in the code shown.

This code will work with C89 (and C99 and C11), without requiring support for variable-length arrays or VLAs — though since I declare variables in `for` loops, the code as written requires C99 or later, but it can easily be fixed to declare the variables outside the `for` loops and it can then compile with C89.

Comment: This looks near-unbelievably similar to the code I was writing during my endless slurry of meetings today, but never had time to commit to an answer (right down to the variable names and the per-segment-size calculations, debug output, etc.). Nice answer, Jonathan, as usual.

Comment: @WhozCraig: thanks.  I need to experiment with [cmaster](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2445184/cmaster)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28819225/15168), and the return values from functions, etc.  In principle, that's nicer (less memory to allocate).  His answer does require a C99 implementation (those must implement VLAs) or a C11 implementation that elects to implement VLAs (it is an option in C11).

Comment: Honestly if C99 VLAs are on the table, the function itself is somewhat pointless, as assuming the max trio is available on the caller side one can simply `double (*matrix)[jmax][kmax] = malloc(imax*sizeof(*matrix));`. If there is some additional initialization in the function, that gives it some reason to live, but not much. Slightly related, there was a helluva Q+A on this site that had a *beautiful* ascii art diagram of this (your) matrix implementation (along with others). For the life of me I couldn't find it, which is a shame. =(

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
void foo(int imax, int jmax, int kmax)
{
   // Allocate memory for all the numbers.
   // Think of this as (imax*jmax) number of memory chunks,
   // with each chunk containing kmax doubles.
   double* data_0 = malloc(imax*jmax*kmax*sizeof(double));

   // Allocate memory for the previus dimension of pointers.
   // This of this as imax number of memory chunks, 
   // with each chunk containing jmax double*.
   double** data_1 = malloc(imax*jmax*sizeof(double*));

   // Allocate memory for the previus dimension of pointers.
   double*** data_2 = malloc(imax*sizeof(double**));

   for (int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
   {
      data_2[i] = &data_1[i*jmax];
      for (int j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
      {
         data_1[i*jmax+j] = &data_0[(i*jmax+j)*kmax];
      }
   }

   // That is the matrix.
   double ***matrix = data_2;

   for (int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
      {
         for (int k = 0; k < kmax; k++)
         {
            matrix[i][j][k] = i+j+k;
         }
      }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
      {
         for (int k = 0; k < kmax; k++)
         {
            printf("%lf ", matrix[i][j][k]);
         }
         printf("\n");
      }
   }

   // Deallocate memory
   free(data_2);
   free(data_1);
   free(data_0);
}
```

Comment: It may work, but it doesn't have a single memory allocation, which is the object of the question, isn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I wonder if the OP wanted to use exactly one call to `malloc` for everything or one call to `malloc` for all the elements of the matrix. I see that you have combined all three memory requirements and used one call to `malloc` in your answer.

Comment: The code in the question shows only a single `malloc()` and then outlines code to futz with pointers.  The question isn't 100% explicit about it, so it could be open to interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This was intended to be a comment but it got too long, until it turned into a proper answer.

---

You can't use a single chunk of memory without performing some calculations.

Note that the beginning of each row is marked by the formula

```
// row_begin is the memory address of the row at index row_idx
row_begin = row_idx * jmax * kmax
```

And then, each column depends on where the row starts:

```
// column_begin is the memory address of the column 
// at index column_idx of the row starting at row_begin
column_begin = row_begin + column_idx * kmax
```

Which, using absolute addresses (relative to the matrix pointer, of course) translates to:

```
column_begin = (row_idx * jmax * kmax) + column_idx * kmax
```

Finally, getting the k-index of an element is very straightforward, following the previous rule this could turn in an infinite recursion:

```
// element address = row_address + column_address + element_k_index
element_k_idx = column_begin + element_k_idx
```

Which translates to

```
element_k_idx = (row_idx * jmax * kmax) + column_idx * kmax + element_k_idx
```

Comment: Since C99, you *can* do without these calculations, letting your compiler do the gory details. See my answer for details.